# Combobox isEditable lostFocus calls when is gets focus

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox that is editable and whenever you click on it, the lostFocus method is invoked. It is also invoked when it actually loses focus.
What is causing the LostFocus to run when I click on the combobox?

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="False"
                  Text="{Binding Model.Number}" ItemsSource="{Binding Item}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Model.Number}"    
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="LostFocus" Command="{Binding TeethLostFocusCommand}" />
    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: So what is the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is causing the LostFocus to run when I click on the combobox?

The fact that `LostFocus` is a *routed* event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This means that your event handler will also be invoked when any element that is a child element of the `ComboBox` - including any element that is part of its `ControlTemplate` - loses focus.

Please refer to the following link for more information about this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7c3ed7d5-c550-4e51-bcb6-32f2b3d0ecf7/focus-issues-with-editable-combobox?forum=wpf